# Mysql: pulling from table

Tags: mysql, join

I am having some trouble putting a query together. I need to show images pulled in the order of if they are in the "editorial" section then if they have an order to be displayed in it will show the editorial image first but if its not ordered in that section it would just default and pull the regular image that is ordered already (which may not be a editorial type image but is a preferred one if nothing else is available). What I have now is the query below BUT that doesn't pull the editorial ranked images first but rather the "ordered_by' seems to take precedence.

```
SELECT i.img_name, a.artist_path_name, a.artist_dir, a.artist_name, ck.catKey_id        
FROM images AS i JOIN artists AS a USING (artist_id)
JOIN img_cat_table AS imc USING ( img_id )
JOIN catkeys AS ck USING (catKey_id)
WHERE site = 'editorial' AND editorial_order = 1 OR ordered_by = 1 GROUP BY artist_name ORDER BY ed_banner
```

Its probably something silly that I am missing -- any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN site = 'editorial' AND editorial_order = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
         ed_banner
```

Answer (score 0):

or the same idea in a simpler way

```
ORDER BY (site = 'editorial' AND editorial_order = 1) DESC, ed_banner
```

It simply utilizes the order of FALSE, TRUE.

You should remove the respective conditions from the WHERE clause.